# Second-order partial derivative of $S = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left(\sum_{i=\max(0,k-n)}^{\min(n,k)}a_{i}a_{k-i}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, summation

Given the following finite sum:

$S = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left(\sum_{i=\max(0,k-n)}^{\min(n,k)}a_{i}a_{k-i}\right)$

From this summation, I want to calculate explicitly each element $(i,j)$, i.e. the partial derivatives, in the Hessian (and with that find an analytical expression), $H_{i,j}$.

The Hessian is calculated in the following way:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H}=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial a_0^2} & \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial a_0 \partial a_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial a_0 \partial a_n} \\
\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial a_1 \partial a_0} & \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial a_1^2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial a_1 \partial a_n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial a_n \partial a_0} & \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial a_n \partial a_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial a_n^2}
\end{array}\right] .
\end{equation}

Example for $n=2$, the result is (without using an analytical expression):
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} \\
\end{bmatrix}

I want a similar result (i.e. an analytical expression) like in this topic to give an idea: [Differentiation of a double summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122110/differentiation-of-a-double-summation).

Comment: We should have $\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial a_m \partial a_p}=2$. You can prove it by applying the Leibnitz rule to the first expression of the sum that you have given

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @shaun I improved the question and gave more context.

Comment: @Math98 your question is a particular case of the link you posted. It is the case $a_{ii}=1$ and $a_{ij}=2$ for $i \ne j$ (try to expand the product in the case $n=2$ or $n=3$)

Comment: Do NOT change your OP, you changed the OP this in this post and you did again here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712964/product-of-two-finite-sums-left-sum-k-0na-k-right-left-sum-k-0nb

Comment: Ok, clear. However, do you know the answer to the question? @MathFail

Comment: @Marco I should get a matrix instead of a scalar as an output. Can you show with an example that my situation is an particular case of the link I posted. I don't follow your reasoning.

Comment: The matrix Is the One with all the coefficients 2. You Just changed your equation. Add context doesn't means changing what you are asking.

Comment: @Shaun Can you delete this question, so I can ask it in a new OP right away correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Note that with respect to your *[previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712964)* $S$ admits due to symmetry the significant simpler representation
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S}&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\sum_{i=\max(0,k-n)}^{\min(n,k)}a_{i}a_{k-i}\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_k\right)^2\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^na_k^2+2\sum_{0\leq k<l\leq n}a_ka_l}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

From (1) it is easily seen that
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\mathbf{H}}&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial a_r \partial a_s}S
\end{bmatrix}_{0\leq r,s\leq n}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a_r \partial a_s}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_k^2+2\sum_{0\leq k<l\leq n}a_ka_l\right)
\end{bmatrix}_{0\leq r,s\leq n}\tag{1}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=
\begin{bmatrix}
2
\end{bmatrix}_{0\leq r,s\leq n}}\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Take the first derivative

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial a_m}=2\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_k\right)\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\partial a_k}{\partial a_m}=2\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_k\right)\sum_{k=0}^n\delta_{km}=2\sum_{k=0}^na_k$$

where $\delta_{km}$ is Kronecker delta.

$$\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial a_m\partial a_p}=2\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\partial a_k}{\partial a_p}=2\sum_{k=0}^n\delta_{kp}=2$$

Comment: I shouldn't get a scalar as output, but a matrix. As an example I added the answer for n=2.

Comment: Do NOT change your OP!

Comment: I needed to, because the OP was closed and it was asked to change it. But in future I will not do it!

Comment: @Math98 You were not asked to *change* your question, but to *improve* your post, by including some thoughts, attempts, efforts to solve it.